# .Net Core 3.1 MVC OAuth Server

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core-3.1

I am trying to migrate OAuth server code written for `.Net Framework 4.5` to `.Net Core 3.1`. The original code pretty much looks like [this](https://www.skylinetechnologies.com/Blog/Skyline-Blog/August-2014/Building-an-OAuth2-Authorization-Server-with-DotNe). It implements the `IAuthorizationServerHost` interface. It makes sense to me that it has some functions that the server should implement (like `CreateAccessToken` that generates and returns a token).

But for `.Net Core 3.1`, `DotNetOpenAuth` is not available. So I searched around and found apparently the best solution [IdentityServer4](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/resources.html) along with many other tutorials ([Tut1](https://feras.blog/how-to-use-asp-net-identity-and-identityserver4-in-your-solution/) [Tut2](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1185880/ASP-NET-Core-WebAPI-secured-using-OAuth-Client-Cre) etc.). But all those looked to me as if they have just implemented the Identity Server (basically just login, logout and register). I don't see how is the token been issued.

My controller class in `.Net Framework 4.5` looks like this. A successful login is usually followed by `oauth/authorize` route that provisions the token and redirects back to the third party.

```
public class OAuthController : Controller
{
    // OAuth2AuthorizationServer is an implementation if IAuthorizationServerHost
    private readonly AuthorizationServer authorizationServer = new AuthorizationServer(new OAuth2AuthorizationServer());

    public ActionResult Token()
    {
        var result = this.authorizationServer.HandleTokenRequest(this.Request).AsActionResult();
        return result;
    }

    [Authorize, AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Authorize()
    {
        var request = this.authorizationServer.ReadAuthorizationRequest(this.Request);
        if (request == null)
        {
            throw new HttpException((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Bad request");
        }
        var response = authorizationServer.PrepareApproveAuthorizationRequest(request, User.Identity.Name);
        return authorizationServer.Channel.PrepareResponse(response).AsActionResult();
    }
}
```

I am new to this authentication stuff - have a quite hollow understanding of the concepts. I am struggling to understand the OAuth server related code flow in these tutorials.

So how can I use those packages to create an OAuth server in `.Net Core 3.1`?

Comment: You don't have to write your own OAuth server, you can use ASP.NET Core Identity or ASP.NET Core Identity Server.

Comment: DotNetOpenAuth was abandoned 7 years ago, so it's not just a matter of compatibility with ASP.NET Core.

Comment: I don't understand the flow in the tutorials mentioned.